# Download javascript file but not evaluate it immediately?

Tags: javascript, performance, page-load-time

I have a large javascript file to use during the web page loading.  I hope it can be downloaded as early as possible (download does not block UI thread) but not evaluated immediately (loading it in memory is in UI thread and blocks domcontentcomplete event and thus the initial page paint).

It will init an XHR to get additional data and update the page.  Users will see the static page early and get all data a little later.  If it is in html head, the initial static page display is delayed.  If it is at page end, download will delay the whole content display.

Is there a way to download but not parse until I initiate the parse later on?

Answer (score 2):

If the JS file isn't critical to rendering you can use the `async` or `defer` attribute on the `<script>` tag for the file. Using `async` will essentially have the same effect as placing the `<script>` tag right before the closing `<body>` tag.

[< Script > - MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/script)

> ## async
>
> HTML5 Set this Boolean attribute to indicate that the browser
>   should, if possible, execute the script asynchronously. It has no
>   effect on inline scripts (i.e., scripts that don't have the src
>   attribute).
>
> ## defer
>
> This Boolean attribute is set to indicate to a browser that the script is meant to be executed after the document has been parsed. Since this feature hasn't yet been implemented by all other major browsers, authors should not assume that the script’s execution will actually be deferred.

You could possibly also use a `setTimeout` call. As long as the `<script>` isn't blocking any rendering, wrapping it in a `setTimeout` should delay it for you.

```
var delay = 10 /* or however many ms you want */
setTimeout(function(){
    /* your code goes here */
}, delay)
```

**edit:** if you're looking to execute specifically after the `DomContentLoaded` event, just wrap your code in an event listener for that event.

```
 document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    /* Your code goes here */
  });
```

Comment: async is to load the file when it is downloaded.  It does not push the loading after domcontetncomplete.   defer is to defer it to afterr page pasrse but before domcontentcomplete too.

Comment: I think you mean `DOMContentLoaded`, there's no event called `DomContentComplete`.  I've updated my answer with a possible solution for you.

Comment: This is an external js file.  Event I wrap all code inside setTimeout in this file, it is too late because by then the js file has been parsed.   Attaching my code to DomContentLoaded event will run my code in event handler.  My understanding is page is painted after DomContentLoaded event is done.

Comment: You said you wanted to defer loading it to avoid blocking the `DomContentLoaded` event from completing. If you have your application evaluate the code inside the event listener, you are guaranteed that your code will be delayed until after `DomContentLoaded` is finished.

Comment: I do not think I can evaluate code in even listener without parsing the js file first.  I am not sure if "defer" will let browser to parse js file before or after domcontentloaded event.  If it is after, it will be a good solution for me.